# What is causing an infinite recursion? (Prolog)

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to approach a problem in which given M and N integers, returns in res a list with the powers of M that are less than or equal to N, in descending order.
example: powers(3,9,res).
res = [9,3,1]

My approach is as follows:

```
power(X,0,1).
power(X,Y,Z) :- X>0,
           Yminus1 is Y - 1,
           power(X,Yminus1,Z1), 
           Z is X*Z1.

increment(X,newX) :- newX is X + 1.

powers(M,N,res) :- integer(M), integer(N),
    powersAux(M,N,0,res).

powersAux(M,N,E,res) :- power(M,E,Z),
                    Z=<N,
                    increment(E,E1),
                    res1 = [Z|res],
                    powersAux(M,N,E1,res1).
```

I'm getting my memory stack filled so I understand that the recursion never ends.

Comment: `res` is a constant (actually an atom) and not variable

Comment: idem `newX`.  []()

Comment: so what's the fix? I'm new to prolog programming @false

Comment: The fix is: first implement `power/3` correctly. But even better, first work with [tag:successor-arithmetics] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle special cases:

- 0<sup>***n***</sup> is always 0
- 1<sup>***n***</sup> is always 1

And Prolog has an in-built exponiation function: `**/2`.

A common Prolog idiom is to have a public predicate that does little outside of constraint validation, that invokes an "internal" helper predicate that does the work. The helper predicate often takes additional parameters that maintain state needed for computation.

That leads to this:

```
powers( X , L, Ps ) :-
    non_negative_integer(X),
    non_negative_integer(L),
    powers(X,0,L,[],Ps)
    .

non_negative_integer(X) :- integer(X), X >= 0 .

% ---------------------------------------------------------------
% 
% powers( +Base, +Exponent, +Limit, +Accumulator, ?Results )
% 
% where Base and Radix are guaranteed to be non-negative integers
% ---------------------------------------------------------------
powers( 0 , _ , _ , _  , [0] ) :- ! .            % 0^n is always 0
powers( 1 , _ , 0 , _  , []  ) :- ! .            % 1^n is always 1
powers( 1 , _ , L , _  , [1] ) :- L >= 1 , !.    % 1^n is always 1
powers( X , Y , L , Ps , Ps  ) :- X**Y >  L , !. % when x^y exceeds the limit, we're done, and
powers( X , Y , L , Ts , Ps  ) :-                % otherrwise...
    T is X**Y ,                                  % - compute T as x^y
    Y1 is Y+1,                                   % - increment Y
    powers(X,Y1,L,[T|Ts],Ps)                     % - recurse down, prepending T to the accumulator list.
    .                                            % Easy!
```

Which gives us

```
?- powers(2,1024,Ps).

Ps = [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll keep in mind those suggestions for future problems